# How to pass viewmodel to fragment using launchFragmentInHiltContainer

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-testing, dagger-hilt

I was trying to write a test case for my fragment. The fragment kind of look like this,

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainFragment : BaseFragment() {
    val viewModel: HomeFragmentViewModel by viewModels()

......
}
```

Now in my test class,

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
@LargeTest
@HiltAndroidTest
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
class MainFragmentTest {
    @get:Rule
    var hiltRule = HiltAndroidRule(this)

    @Before
    fun init() {
        hiltRule.inject()
    }

    @Test
    fun testFragmentDisplays() {
        val fakeRepository = FakeRepository()
        val scenerio = launchFragmentInHiltContainer<MainFragment>() {
            //(this as MainFragment).viewModel = HomeFragmentViewModel(fakeRepository)
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is viewModel in the Fragment is `val` and it has to be `val` because I am using `viewModels()` to create the viewmodel. Is there anyway I can create the viewmodel and use in my fragment?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make Your BaseFragment Like This

```
abstract class BaseFragment<VM: ViewModel>: Fragment() {

protected lateinit var viewModel: VM

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(getViewModelClass())
.....
    }
}
```

Then Extend it Like This

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainFragment : BaseFragment<HomeFragmentViewModel>() {
   
......
}
```

And `HomeFragmentViewModel` Should be like this

```
@HiltViewModel
class HomeFragmentViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val YourRepository: YourRepository
) : ViewModel() {

........

}
```

Comment: `by viewModels()` does **exactly** the same thing as `ViewModelProvider(this).get(getViewModelClass())`, that change is entirely unnecessary to solving this problem.

Comment: Thanks.. but I was still wondering if we could use that lazy style